# Jackson parse json with unwraping root, but without ability to set @JsonRootName

Tags: java, json, jackson

The rest service responds with

```
<transaction><trxNumber>1243654</trxNumber><type>INVOICE</type></transaction>
```

or in JSON:

```
{"transaction":{"trxNumber":1243654,"type":"INVOICE"}}
```

There is no problems when I use:

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)
```

And as resulting class

```
@JsonRootName("transaction")
public class Transaction {
private String trxNumber;
private String type;
//getters and setters
}
```

But actually I should use the Transaction class from 3rd party jar, which is exact like above, **but has no @JsonRootName("transaction") annotation.**

So I end up with

```
Could not read JSON: Root name 'transaction' does not match expected ('Transaction') for type...
```

Is there any ways to force Jackson parse to Transaction class without adding any stuff to the Transaction class itself (as I get this file as part of a binary jar)?

I've tried custom PropertyNamingStrategy, but it seems has to do only with field and getter/setter names, but not class names.

Java7, Jackson 2.0.5.

Any suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with [mixin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) feature. You can create simple interface/abstract class like this:

```
@JsonRootName("transaction")
interface TransactionMixIn {

}
```

Now, you have to configure `ObjectMapper` object:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Transaction.class, TransactionMixIn.class);
```

And finally you can use it to deserialize JSON:

```
mapper.readValue(json, Transaction.class);
```

Second option - you can write [custom deserializer](http://pilhuhn.blogspot.com/2013/07/custom-deserializer-in-jackson-and.html) for `Transaction` class.

Comment: Great! thank you a lot for the answer. Finally we gecided to go with TransactionWrapper object and put @JsonRootName("transaction") on its Transaction field, but your suggestion looks very interesting!

Comment: `TransactionWrapper` sounds good. I thought about it also. Anyway you could reuse mixin feature to solve another problems in the future.